How can I separate blog content from astro blog-site-code using Git
I have a prototype astro SSR blog. I want to separate the content from the site code so that I can version them independently and allow content collaboration without exposing site code to collaborators, etc.

Not looking to modify the astro blog itself - need pure Git approach
The site is deployed on a self-hosted Node server
Project contains a dev branch and a prod branch
Updating the server involves pulling from the prod branch and such, then rebuilding
No ci/cd at the moment, but need to leave that option open
No collaborators at the moment, however need to be open to collaboration in the future
I can only require collaborators to have GitHub account and Git installed on their machines. They will only work with Markdown files
Git developer access tokens used for collaborator access control

I've  looked at:

git submodules and subtrees

Challenging workflow for tech-challenged collaborators
Deployment complexities
Total disaster fixing git setups for collaborators when things go wrong


Manually pull/push content to both collaborators and prod

Straightforward, but considerable workflow



I need to decide which structure/methodology to implement. The collaborators participation is "opt-in" -meaning if it's too hard, they just won't do it. I don't want to get it working great for myself, but too complicated for a content editor to want to deal with.
I don't see many collaborators coming onboard at this time and can tolerate a bit more setup/update complexity, however, I am sensitive to the possibility of needing to switch into emergency mode when/if the subtree/submodule scheme gets out of whack.
Which best-practices and approaches would be viable options for this project?

If I were you, I would just use something like https://decapcms.org. (Also, but this is unrelated, I would statically generate the blog and host on e.g. Netlify – why? because it's simpler)
